# I am unable to send a message using .php

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I am unable to send a message using .php.

Strangely, I have tested and been able to send messages in the past, but for some reason I now get the message '* The Message field must contain only letters, digits, spaces and basic punctuation ( ' - , . ), has a limit of 1000 characters & should not be left empty. '.

I'm aware that it's a message gerneaed due to  conflict in the message form and the .php, but don't have the skill to rectify it.

I built a website a while back using the same contact & .php forms and that too has the same problem.

Please advise:

```
<?php


$your_email = "mailto@host.com"; // email address to which the form data will be sent
$subject = "Subject Here"; // subject of the email that is sent
$thanks_page = "/thankyou/"; // path to the thank you page following successful form submission
$contact_page = "http://test.com/contact/index.html"; // path to the HTML contact page where the form appears



if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    header( "Location: $contact_page" );
  }

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $nam = $_POST["name"];
    $ema = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $mes = $_POST["message"];
    $spa = $_POST["spam"];

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { 
    $nam = stripslashes($nam);
    $ema = stripslashes($ema);
    $mes = stripslashes($mes);
    }

$error_msg=array(); 

if (empty($nam) || !preg_match("~^[a-z\-'\s]{1,60}$~i", $nam)) { 
$error_msg[] = "<br/>* The name field must contain only letters, spaces, dashes ( - ) and single quotes ( ' ).\n<br />\n<br />";
}

if (empty($ema) || !filter_var($ema, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error_msg[] = "<br/>* Your email must have a valid format, such as name@mailhost.com\n<br />\n<br />";
}

$limit = 1000;

if (empty($mes) || !preg_match("/^[0-9A-Za-z\/-\s'\(\)!\?\.,]+$/", $mes) || (strlen($mes) > $limit)) { 
$error_msg[] = "<br/>* The Message field must contain only letters, digits, spaces and basic punctuation (&nbsp;'&nbsp;-&nbsp;,&nbsp;.&nbsp;), has a limit of 1000 characters &amp; should not be left empty.\n<br />\n<br />";
}

if (!empty($spa) && !($spa == "4" || $spa == "four")) {
    echo "* You failed the spam test! Please go back and try again.\n<br />\n<br />";
    exit ();
}

if ($error_msg) {
echo '<!--CONTACT--->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html lang="en-US" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html lang="en-US" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en-US" class="no-js lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html lang="en-US" class="js"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>';
exit();
} 

$email_body = 
    "Name of Sender: $nam\n\n" .
    "Email: $ema\n\n" .
    "Message:\n\n" .
    "$mes" ; 


if (isset($_REQUEST['message']) && !$error_msg) {
mail ($your_email, $subject, $email_body, "From: $nam <$ema>" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: $nam <$ema>");
header ("Location: $thanks_page");
exit();
}  
}
```

An example of the contact form working incorrectly can be tried here - http://mickscaricatures.co.uk/contact.html

Is there any further information I can supply to help resolve this situation?

Comment: Gave it a try and it seemed to work fine for me.  Are you sure it's broken?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php tag error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and check your error logs.

Comment: You're right Casey. It seems to be working fine now. Can you try this one too please - http://davidhubber.com/contact/ - Could it have anything to do with a the PHP version being used on my host?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an escape in your regex for the $mes parameter:

```
[..snip..]\/-\s[..snip..]
            ^---
```

Since that `-` is not escaped, it's treated as `any chars from slash to space`.

Comment: Could you explain a little better please. I really don't know how this works. Thanks

Comment: `[a-z]` is "all characters between `a` and `z`. `[a\-z]` is "must be either `a`, a dash, or a `z`".  So like I said, the indicated dash isn't escaped.